# file always null when post using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

It works file when upload via postman but it didnt work when upload using anularjs

.netcore controller

```
[HttpPost, Route("csv/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StudentCSV(IFormFile file)
```

html:

```
<div class="btn btn-rounded form-control">
 <input type="file"  class="input_file form-control" placeholder="select file">
</div>
```

angular controller:

```
 var myfile = $('.input_file').prop('files');

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", myfile);

  UniversityService.UploadCSV(formData).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
  });
```

angular service

```
function UploadCSV(file) {

        CoreService.Post(url+ '/csv/upload/',file).then(function (response) {
            deferer.resolve(response);
        })
    }
```

> the issue here is that `file` always null!

Answer (score 0):

-You can use directive instead of mixing Jquery with Angularjs but to solve this issue change the upload function to something like this:

```
 $scope.upload = function () {

    var myfile = $('.input_file').prop('files');

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", myfile[0]);// specify only one file 

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/csv/upload',
        data: formData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }// set contenct-type undefined
    }).then(function (result) {

    }, function (error) {

    })

}
```